# connecting to HP ALM using REST api JAVA

Tags: java, rest, hp-quality-center

I want to connect to HP ALM 11 using java. I've heard that using REST api i can connect to HP ALM.

1) Can someone tell me where can I get REST api download and its documentation? 
2) Is it provided by HP or its developed by third party? 
3) Is there any api provided or recommended by HP?

Answer (score 2):

The REST API is part of HP ALM 11. Check out Wikipedia article on [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) for some background information.

The REST API documentation is available on the HP web site (requires HP Passport sign-in):

http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/KM997956/binary/ALM11.00_REST_API.html?searchIdentifier=-765a98c0%3a12de84ca170%3a-27ac&resultType=document